# how to change title for only "checkout" in wocommerce wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know how to change checkout text. Please help me out to give me `function.php` code I will use to my website.
[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGE CHECKOUT TEXT**

- Open function.php theme file using FPT or admin theme editor

Add the following code at the bottom of function.php file & Save the changes

```
<?php function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() { 
$checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); ?> 
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() );?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Secure Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</a> <?php } ?>
```